# Method to parse request_uri header from decoded JSON in Perl

Tags: perl, rest

Ok, so here is what we are doing. We are viewing a json request/response string.

Code snippet (assuming relevant modules been used):

```
 if( open( my $json_file, $filename ))
 {
    my $json = JSON->new;
    my $data = $json->decode(<$json_file>);
    close( json_file );
    $request_uri = $data->{'input'}{'Headers'}{'REQUEST_URI'}; 
 }
```

So $request_uri looks something like

```
 /user/12345?param1=4&param2=9956
```

Whilst I could use regex or whatever to extract data out of there, I am sure this is a common situation and there should be a method to parse this particular REST into its parts and then extract them out. I do not see this in the REST manual which seems to be more about constructing requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [URI](https://metacpan.org/module/URI) module.

```
my $request_uri = URI->new( $data->{'input'}{'Headers'}{'REQUEST_URI'} );

my $path  = $request_uri->path;
my $query = $request_uri->query;
# etc
```

Comment: Thank you. I will see how query can be broken up further (it is one big parameter list) but this is a useful place to start.

Comment: @CashCow, You actually want `->query_form` to break down the params.

Comment: Thank you but actually the json contains the parameters already in input/Parameters so there is no need to do this.

The answer given is useful to extract the path out, and the parameters if I want it as a single string.